# Page getting blank while downloading pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf

The current page getting blank whenever i download pdf file in vf page.Here is my code:
[image]

This is the UI code:

```
 <button aria-live="assertive"
                class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected"
                id="pdfView">Export as PDF</button>
```

javascript function:

```
 $('#pdfView').click
            (
                function()
                {
                    var param = 'apex/Invention_Disclosure_PDF?id='+getParameterByName("id");           
                    redirectToURL(param);
                }
            );
```

Current page is getting blank and then pdf file is downloading,how to avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use an anchor tag instead of a button and style it as a button, you could even use the download attribute to give the browser an extra hint that it's a file download.

Assuming you page is using the Standard Controller for your object then it would look something like this:

```
<a aria-live="assertive"
    class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected"
    href="/apex/Invention_Disclosure_PDF?id={!Object_Name__c.Id}"
    download="true">Export as PDF</a>
```